# A challenge on the parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good Night ...
Here I am editing the question and explaining the purpose of the same ...
Mathematics course, and I love this science, I am very curious, and these days, studying a book of calculus found in (book from the library of the University) a sheet full of challenges, to share with a colleague, he gave me this challenge, which he also failed to respond ...
I tried, I tried, I used the formulas of quadratic equation, and I've been trying since Friday (here in Brazil is Sunday at 22:33), and could not, and I ask your help, and please believe me, I struggled, tried to make substitutions, tried both, and I'm confused ... I must find the values of $ a, b $ and $ c $?

Consider a parabola whose roots, other are $x'$ and $x''$, and such that $x'=-x''$ where $x'> 0$. Let $$A = (x', 0)$$ $$B = (x'', 0)$$ and $V$ the vertex of the parabola. Suppose that the equation of this parabola is $$y = ax^2 +bx+ c$$. Calculate the value of the discriminant $$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$, so that the triangle is equilateral AVB.

Comment: Source? Reason for interest? Evidence of effort, beyond copy-paste?

Comment: I am passionate about mathematics, and found it interesting, unfortunately I could not solve, so I decided to ask for help from those who can. Since the source was a guy passed me and said he found it interesting that one also failed to respond.
No need to say "copy and paste" unfortunately felt offended.

Comment: Sorry you feel offended. I feel offended when people post problems here with no indication of where they come from, no indication of why anyone would be interested, and no indication that they have put the tiniest amount of thought into the problem. But I'll get over it.

Comment: People are not equal my dear friend, I asked for interest, and you've come judging me. For your information this is no college work. It's just my curiosity. And have you excused it.

Comment: It's not a matter of judging, it's a matter of how some of us like to see questions presented on this website. In particular, we like to see some indication that the person posting the question has made some effort to answer it. Five people (and I wasn't one of them) felt strongly enough about it to vote to close the question, so I'm not the only one who likes to see a sign that people have tried to solve the questions they present. You can edit the question and ask for reopening. Homework or not, the links elsewhere on this page will help you rewrite it.

Comment: Edited, and please believe me, I really love math, and I'm here to learn, not prop up people. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you are asked to find the value of the discriminant, not the separate values of $a, b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the roots are opposite, then the function $y(x)$ that describes the parabola is an even function of $x$, i.e. $y(x)=y(-x)$. This implies that $b=0$.
This allows us to simplify all the relevant formulas:

$$\Delta = -4ac \qquad,\qquad V=\left(-\dfrac b{2a},-\dfrac\Delta{4a}\right)=(0,c)$$

The distance $OV$ is the height of the equilateral triangle, so it is related to the side $AB=|x'-x''|=2x'$:

$$OV = |c| = \dfrac{\sqrt3}2 AB = \sqrt3x'$$

Let's assume (for the moment) $c>0$. Since the product of the roots satisfies $x'x''=\dfrac ca$, we obtain

$$x'x'' = -x'^2 = \dfrac ca \quad\to\quad a = -\dfrac c{x'^2} = -\dfrac{\sqrt3}{x'} < 0$$

Finally, $$\Delta=-4ac=12$$

Notice that we found a solution with $a<0,c>0$, but there exists a symmetrical solution with $a>0,c<0$ and the same discriminant: it is obtained letting $c<0$ and doing the following steps.

Comment: The vertex is $$x=0$$

Comment: It is an even function

Comment: Cedo para concluir que o $$b/(2a)=0 \Longrightarrow b=0$$?

Comment: The value of $b=0$?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: The conclusion is correct, even if I'm not sure that you got it from my hint. That said, what can you say about the discriminant? Do you see that you have two (symmetric) cases to consider? What about the $y$ coordinate of the vertex $V$ of the triangle?

Technical note: please, don't add many comments with little content. To let a user know that you commented, use the @[username] command.

Comment: I don't think the given data is that the two roots are (of) opposite (sign): it is given the roots are $\,x\,,\,x''\,$ and then he defines $x'=-x''\;$ (terrible choice of letters, imo.)

Comment: @AndreaOrta Orta:
I'm new here yet, sorry, and thanks for the tip. Already on the Question, following a function and symmetric about the axis $ y $ and we have what temperature the vertex coordinates $$V=(0,-\frac{\Delta}{4a})$$ We are also clear that $x'$ e $x''$ is $2x'$.

Comment: Ok @marcelolpjunior , so if you already have that the abscissa of the vertex is zero then $$-\frac b{2a}=0\iff b= 0$$ and the parabolla indeed is an even function...

Comment: @DonAntonio It is the most common here in Brazil lol

Comment: @marcelopjunior: Please, note the comment by DonAntonio. Is it your assumption that $x'=-x''$, or is it included in the problem statement? As DonAntonio points out, it is not necessary: the problem can be solved either ways. Moreover, I think it's better if you edit the question writing clearly the text of the problem and trying to put in order the first steps of your solution.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, I can't believe that. Either you use capital letters, say $\,X\, $ , for variables, or any other difference must exist there to tell appart variables and values.

Comment: @AndreaOrta: Na verdade o problema anuncia que $$x'=-x''$$
It could be concluded that $$d(A,B)=2x'$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Here in Brazil we use usual $$x';x'';{x_1};{x_2}$$ to the roots of quadratic equations.

Comment: That's fine, @marcelolpjunior...but not $\,x\,$ as one of the roots as you wrote!

Comment: So to speak, in the interpretation of the challenge, I have to find the values ​​of $a$, $b$ and $c$?
In which we have discovered that $b=0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I presume that was simply a typo. I edited the question to make it clearer.
Marcelo, you don't have to calculate $a,b,c$: the problem makes it clear that you have to calculate the discriminant $\Delta$!

Comment: @Andrea Orta: Mas não é necessário saber $a$, $b$ e $c$?

Comment: @Andrea Orta:
So, I know that $$d(A,V)=d(V,B)=d(A,B)=2x'$$;
We have the discriminant is non-zero, we have the parable is a function, and until $\Delta\neq0$, And then, with this information, what is it? What would be so necessary to proceed in the calculations?

Comment: @AndreaOrta: Still do not understand where I'm coming.

Comment: @marcelopjunior: All right. I think this exchange of comments is not constructive, so give me some minutes and I'll change my answer in a full solution.

Comment: @AndreaOrta: Yes, but can I ask you something about the solution? Because I'd really like to learn. Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: Can I suggest drawing a diagram? And can you express the coefficients of the quadratic in terms of $x'$ and $a$ ie the roots and the leading coefficient (which is always possible for a polynomial)?

Comment: @MarkBennet: Great for me.

Comment: @AndreaOrta
The fact of the matter is closed does not disturb you post the solution?

Comment: I didn't understand. Did you see the solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: @AndreaOrta
Sorry, I see the solution now, just a minute.

Comment: @AndreaOrta:
Sorry, did not understand where he appeared 12

Comment: @AndreaOrta
In the third line, would not be
$$\qquad V=\left(-\dfrac b{2a},-\dfrac\Delta{4a}\right)=(0,-c)$$????

Comment: No, it's $(0,c)$, because $\Delta=-4ac$. And 12 comes from multiplying the expressions for $a$ and $c$, that we found as functions of $x'$.

Comment: @AndreaOrta: I could understand, lol, man, thank enough, it was amazing, all the ways I tried did not come out, I think it's because I have not used the height of the equilateral triangle, thank you, and I found this very interesting challenge. Cheers, Thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio
Thanks for the strength that I had too.

Comment: @marcelopjunior: You are welcome. As an additional challenge, you could try to think about the same problem, but without the assumption $x'=-x''$. As you can see drawing a picture, there's no reason why the problem couldn't be solved in that (more general) setting. Of course, you'll find more cumbersome expressions! =)

Comment: Please avoid extended conversations in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: it must be

$$AB=|x''-x| = AV= VB$$

Now:

$$V=\left(-\frac b{2a}\;,\;-\frac\Delta{4a}\right)\;,\;\;x,x''=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2a}$$

And you also know that $\,\Delta>0\,$ (because of the mild assumption $\,x\neq x''\,$).

Well, now try to do some mathematics here.

Further hint: you may also want to use that

$$xx''=\frac ca\;,\;\;x+x''=-\frac ba\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: I'll try, thanks for the tips, if I can not I can return to ask him?

Comment: Sure (seguro, por supuesto). Write back if you get stuck somewhere after trying the above.

Comment: I'm not getting.

Comment: I managed to find that $$b = 0$$